# Finding point inside pointcloud

Tags: matlab, point-clouds

I have a pointcloud made by X Y Z matrices. They make a volume. I want to check if a point (x, y, z) is inside this cloud, e. g. in the volume that is inside the pointcloud. How can I do this in Matlab?

I have tried to simply extrapolate Xmax, Xmin, Ymax,Ymin and Zmin and Zmax, and finding points that are between these values. However, the shape is irregular, so this gives points which are not inside the cloud.

Does the pointCloud function in MatLab give the option to check if a set of points is inside a given cloud?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use 3 calls to [`inpolygon`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) to check if points are within each of the `X-Y`, `X-Z` and `Y-Z` views?

Comment: I don't think so, because the shape is so weird. I think you will end up with the same issue as now.

Comment: The problem here centers around how you want to define the **surface** of the point cloud (which you then check to see if a point is within). You say the shape is irregular, but is it [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron) or concave (e.g. it has holes or indentations)? You can compute a 3-D convex surface using [`delaunayTriangulation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.html) and test whether or not a point is inside the convex hull using the [`pointLocation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.pointlocation.html) method.

Comment: I found a routine using delaunay triangulation to extrapolate the surface. However, since the surface is quite rough, this doesn't really work.
TRI = delaunay(x,y,z);
trimesh(TRI, x, y, z);
 What I could to, is to smooth the surface, before using triangulation

Comment: The surface is like a spherical cylinder, but with a large number of surface irregularities.